# Stack Exchange API - getting answers for the questions object

Tags: support, api

I use https://api.stackexchange.com/docs. To get a sample question, I use the address `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/6827752?&site=stackoverflow`. Thanks to this, he gains a question. The following page shows https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/question that with the default filter the question will not have a body. I know I use a filter to get a body `filter=withbody` that is, the address comes out

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/6827752?&site=stackoverflow&filter=withbody
```

Now I would like to get answers for the question. That's why I want to use a filter `filter=withanswers`. This address

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/6827752?&site=stackoverflow&filter=withanswers
```

returns an error

```
{
  "error_id": 400,
  "error_message": "Invalid filter specified",
  "error_name": "bad_parameter"
}
```

How do get answers or comments using a filter?

Answer (score 5):

You have to use a custom filter, the [default](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters) provided filters are not going to cut it.

Here is an example for question id [4 on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4/while-applying-opacity-to-a-form-should-we-use-a-decimal-or-a-double-value)

> [`https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=4&filter=!-y(KwOdKR5Ga7mmruVArx2SJykc-M)3jKiDQBk1fq&site=stackoverflow&run=true`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=4&filter=!-y(KwOdKR5Ga7mmruVArx2SJykc-M)3jKiDQBk1fq&site=stackoverflow&run=true)

The filter value `!-y(KwOdKR5Ga7mmruVArx2SJykc-M)3jKiDQBk1fq` will return questions, answers and their comments.

See my answer on [How to create API filters?](https://stackapps.com/questions/6815/how-to-create-api-filters/6908#6908) to learn how to create filters in the UI.