# Get questions + answers from a certain tag for the last six months

Tags: support, tag-filters

I want to do some text analysis on the body of the questions and answers of certain tags, starting with `pandas` and `numpy`. I want to start with the last six months.

I know how to get the body of the questions:

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/43225521?&site=stackoverflow&filter=withbody
```

**Question**:

But how do I get the answers / questions only for the `pandas` tag and for the last six months?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the tags to the tagged field.

[`tagged=pandas;numpy&site=stackoverflow&filter=!9_bDDxJY5`](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=pandas%3Bnumpy&site=stackoverflow&filter=!9_bDDxJY5)

Use a `;` to separate multiple tags.

From the [documentation page](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=pandas%3Bnumpy&filter=!9_bDDxJUK&site=stackoverflow&run=false)

> To constrain questions returned to those with a set of tags, use the tagged parameter with a semi-colon delimited list of tags. This is an and constraint, passing tagged=c;java will return only those questions with both tags. As such, passing more than 5 tags will always return zero results.

Comment: Thanks, will try. WHat is the last filter you added? `filter=!9_bDDxJY5`? Also when I look in the [documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true) I could not find anything about tags, where did you find the documentation?

Comment: @Erfan you're looking at the single question doc. I looked at the questions overall page as I assumed you wanted to search / select those questions. I edited the filter to include the body field and wanted to verify if answers where part of the response

Comment: I see, thanks for the help, this solves it for now, I guess I have to play around with the filters, don't understand them yet, `2.2/answers?order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=pandas&site=stackoverflow&filter=withbody` does not work.

Comment: @Erfan if you need guidance on filters see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306515/158100 and https://stackapps.com/questions/6815/how-to-create-api-filters/6908#6908